# How to set dynamic state in nested looping in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a form with multiple profiles, every form will contains 2 or 3 profiles so, im looping the profiles in a form. Every single profile will have name field we can add more name fields by click on more button, here when i'm trying to add more name fields to profile 1, the appended name fields are appending to other profiles too.

I need to restrict the appending, need to append respected fields to individual profiles.

Here is the code what i have tried till now

```
this.state = {
  aliasNameRow:  [],
  alias_name1:   []

}

addAliasInput(event) {
  for(let j=0;j<this.props.edit_person.data.length;j++){
    let alias_name1 = this.state.alias_name1;

     alias_name1[event.index] = {...alias_name1[event.index], 
     [event.id]:event.data.id,[event.element]:event.value};

     this.setState({
        ...this.state,
         alias_name1:alias_name1
     });
}

 _addAlias(data,j){

   this.state.aliasNameRow.push(index++)       
   this.setState({ aliasNameRow: this.state.aliasNameRow})      

 }
render(){
  return(

   <Button  transparent={true}  onPress={this._addAlias.bind(this,data,j)} >
         <Image source={require('../../images/blue-plus-sign-md.png')} style={{width:30,height:30}}/>
      </Button>
 this.state.aliasNameRow.map((r, i) => {
      return <View key={ i } style={[styles.row, CheckIndex(i)]}>
      <Input
      style={{marginLeft:15,marginTop:4,paddingLeft:10,paddingRight:10,height:40,borderWidth:1,borderColor:'#ccc'}}
      value={(this.state.alias_name1[i])?this.state.alias_name1[i].alias_name1:''}
      onChangeText={(value) => this.addAliasInput({index:i, id:'id' , element:'alias_name1', value:value,data})}
      maxLength={150}
      multiline={true}
      numberOfLines={5}
      placeholder='Enter Alias'
      returnKeyType={'done'}
      editable={ true }
      blurOnSubmit={false}
      multiline={true}
      />
     </View>
  })}
 )
}
```

Please let me know where i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hello anyone help me out

Comment: It's hard to see the flow due to (I think) most of the code have been cut. Is the other profiles affected whenever you type the alias? If yes, perhaps the issue is in addAliasInput function.

Comment: yes when we adding alias in profile 1, profile 2 got effecting